# Netbeans 8.2 with MinGW Error 2

Tags: c, windows, gcc, netbeans

I've made a simple Hello World program in C, but I keep getting error 2.

I'm using Netbeans 8.2 with MinGW.

```
cd 'C:\Users\Diogo\Desktop\teste'
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Diogo/Desktop/teste'
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/teste.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Diogo/Desktop/teste'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
gcc     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/teste build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/newfile.o 
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/newfile.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\Diogo\Desktop\teste/newfile.c:2: multiple definition of `main'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o:C:\Users\Diogo\Desktop\teste/main.c:20: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/teste.exe] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Diogo/Desktop/teste'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Diogo/Desktop/teste'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

How to solve the error?

Comment: per the output from the linker, there is more than one instance of a 'main()` function.

Comment: please format the terminal output for readability.  Post the mingw config file, post the source code, post the makefile.   Are you sure there is only one active project?

Comment: @Reigota "simple Hello World program in c" -- If that's the case, why did you tag your question as C++? Please, don't spam tags.